# In any language how can applications (GUI) be architectural (built) to enable organisation to be clear and reasonably easy to apply new problems?

Tags: language-agnostic

I pose this question: **How can applications (GUI) be architectural (built) to enable organisation to be clear and reasonably easy to apply new problems?**

This isn't language specific and its more general.

Comment: An architecture question like this one would be better on programmers.stackexchange.com, no ?

Comment: Your question is too unspecific. Basically it says: How can one write good software? Millions of developers are struggling with that topic for the last decades. And there will be no end to that in the near future...

Comment: Hello Thomas, I was just looking for common ways programmers are using to overcome this huge issue. The ideas generated are an incite - notably separation of concerns, The SOLID principles and with the use of Design Patterns

Comment: @Riduidel - Good Steer - Hadn't heard of that site before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separation of Concerns, ensure the GUI isn't tied closely to underlying business logic then you'll be better positioned to update/replace the GUI as needed without tons of work on the rest of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Next to separation of concerns, I find the ['open closed principle'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) very important.

That means that, you should be able to tackle new situations by adding new implementations of interfaces/base classes, instead of modifying existing classes.

In fact, every single principle of the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) principle should be adhered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get this question. I'd have thought that as long as you follow the human interface guidelines for the given platform ([Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657751%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGIntro/XHIGIntro.html) for example) and use common UI patterns then all should be well.

Then again, perhaps you're talking about the underlying code, in which case a separation of concerns through the use of [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller) (or one of the variations such as [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel), etc.) would seem an ideal solution.

Comment: separation of concerns was one of the key points raised, I will research MVVC a bit more.

Comment: @JHarley1 I wouldn't focus on MVVC too much at the moment - think it's perhaps still a bit of a Microsoft oddity. That said, MVC is definitely worthy of investigation.

Comment: MVVC? Do we mean MVVM? There's MVP as well as another SoC like pattern.

Comment: @Lazarus - Ahh.. that's the one. Thanks for the comment - I'll update my answer. :-)

Comment: Yeah... so many Ms and Vs, it's a clunky acronym too as it really should be MVV (Model View Viewmodel) but that's even more confusing... which V would be which! LOL I'm so glad it's nearly time to head home!

Answer (score 0):

Design patterns try to answer this very question.  Please take a look at some of the popular design patterns out there.  A good place to start would be on the [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_patterns) wiki page.

Comment: I don't think that this is true; design patterns try to tackle common problems/situations.  However, the principles that are used in design patterns can be used in your own software as well, in order to tackle the problems the topicstarter mentions.

Comment: Interesting to have some differing opinions.